# Filter value not selected after jqgrid reload

Tags: jqgrid

I have a filter(select option) and search button after clicked search grid loaded but what ever i Have selected filter value de selected. So any Help Please How to retail filter value to be selected.

Comment: You should describe the problem more detailed. It's good to post the code which you use. Pictures could be helpful too. The current text of your question can be interpreted in many ways. You write about the "filter" and "search" button. Do use only Searching Dialog or filter toolbar or both? What is your problem? Is some select element not working on the second opening of Search Dialog or you want that the values of the filter toolbar will be changed after applying of search in the Search Dialog? Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid (free jqGrid, commercial Guriddo,..)

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!